# C Programming and vim

Tags: c, vim, ide, editor

I have practically no experience with programming outside of ide's (Microsoft Visual Studio, netbeans and eclipse) and I am beginning to learn C programming. I have adequate experience with C++ and Java. I have downloaded gVim 7.3 and am looking for some guidance on how to program in C with vim. I do not even know where to type code with vim! I am completely lost and am looking for instructions to run simple command-line programs such as hello-world (to start). Also, would notepad++ be of any use? 
Somebody please show me the world of C programming and Vim

Comment: These are text editors. You have to associate your C compiler with them.

Comment: This seems like a very broad question, so I'm voting to close.  The major gotcha for new users to vim are the different modes, which is why you're finding it hard to type in something. Just do a search for beginner vim tutorials. Expect to start out very slow, with not much productivity.  If you're not willing to make that adjustment, I would say stick with something more simple like Notepad++.

Comment: I hope this helps: http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2009/01/tutorial-make-vim-as-your-cc-ide-using-cvim-plugin/

Comment: Are you using Windows or Linux?  If you're using Linux, you should already have GCC (for a compiler).

Comment: Is it worth learning to use Vim?

Comment: Why do you want to learn Vim?

Comment: its definitely worth using Vim for a little bit,  there is a plugin for visual studio that gives Vim like bindings.   The reason vim is worth learning is that you learn to think a little differently about text editing,  that you can be quite efficient, and the computer should be able to do the grunt work,  rather than manually editing things.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually its done like this - you open up a shell window, set your compile enviroment configuration. Then open any files you are working on with gvim to have a C syntax highlighting available, modify them and save. Get back to shell window repeat make command or whatever you need to compile and link application.

The usefull extension for me was ctags, which allows to browse declarations. You dont get the comfort of code completions, intelissence, on-the-fly error messages or list of function parameters, but I didnt miss that much eitherway.